# Replacing variable text with same root in python

Tags: python

Hello iam new to python i have this simple code to replace text.
Everythink work but i need to replace **-Phsig 33** part for **-DeviceMap "32"** with Quotes added and with lower number by one than previous. Its somehow easy possible?

```
import os
import shutil

os.chdir('C:\\konverze')

print(os.getcwd())

print (os.listdir())

shutil.copy2('C:\\konverze\EIO.CFG', 'C:\\konverze\EIO_konvertovane.CFG')

print ("kopírování File EIO.CFG bylo úspěšné")

s = open("EIO.CFG").read()
s = s.replace('-Unit', '-Device')
s = s.replace('-Type', '-SignalType')
s = s.replace('-Phsig', '-DeviceMap')

f = open("EIO_konvertovane.CFG", 'w')
f.write(s)
f.close()
```

sample of TXT file:

```
  -Name "diSPARE00" -Type "DI" -Unit "SIM_BOARD" -Phsig 1

  -Name "doMotOnState" -Type "DO" -Unit "DP_BOARD" -Phsig 33\
  -Access "System"

  -Name "doService" -Type "DO" -Unit "DP_BOARD" -Phsig 44 -Access "All"
```

desired result:

```
  -Name "diSPARE00" -SignalType "DI" -Device "SIM_BOARD" -DeviceMap "0"

  -Name "doMotOnState" -SignalType "DO" -Device "DP_BOARD" -DeviceMap "32"\
  -Access "System"

  -Name "doService" -SignalType "DO" -Device "DP_BOARD" -DeviceMap "43" -Access "All"
```

Thank you very much for advice

Comment: What do you want to replace `-Phsig 10`: `-DeviceMap "9"` or `-DeviceMap "09"` or `-DeviceMap " 9"` or `-DeviceMap "9 "` or something else? Also, do you understand regular expressions well enough to use them or do you want to avoid them? Finally, it would help if you show us the desired result from the example input TXT file.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for fast response i Added desired result everythink is fine in my code. I only dont know how to add  " " to last number and lower it by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split your text into lines and look for '-DeviceMap' in each line and then replace number after that by this number decremented by 1 and surrounded by `"`

```
s = """\
  -Name "diSPARE00" -Type "DI" -Unit "SIM_BOARD" -Phsig 1

  -Name "doMotOnState" -Type "DO" -Unit "DP_BOARD" -Phsig 33\
  -Access "System"

  -Name "doService" -Type "DO" -Unit "DP_BOARD" -Phsig 44 -Access "All"\
"""

s = s.replace('-Unit', '-Device')
s = s.replace('-Type', '-SignalType')
s = s.replace('-Phsig', '-DeviceMap')

s = s.splitlines()
new_s = []

for line in s:
    line = line.split(' ')
    if '-DeviceMap' in line:
        line[line.index('-DeviceMap')+1] = '"{}"'.format(int(line[line.index('-DeviceMap')+1]) - 1)
    new_s.append(' '.join(line))

s = '\n'.join(new_s)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
  -Name "diSPARE00" -SignalType "DI" -Device "SIM_BOARD" -DeviceMap "0"

  -Name "doMotOnState" -SignalType "DO" -Device "DP_BOARD" -DeviceMap "32"  -Access "System"

  -Name "doService" -SignalType "DO" -Device "DP_BOARD" -DeviceMap "43" -Access "All"
```

---

If there might be additional characters except for decimals in word after 'Phsig' you could replace them with nothing, like so:

`'33\\'.replace('\\', '') # -> '33'`

So in our final code we'll change line that threw error to:

```
        line[line.index('-DeviceMap')+1] = '"{}"'.format(int(line[line.index('-DeviceMap')+1].replace('\\', '')) - 1)
```

Comment: Hello everythink work fine until this come :  -Name "diResetError" -Type "DI" -Unit "DP_BOARD" -Phsig 40\
      -Access "System"

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\_programy_inst_new\python\edit_cfg.py", line 25, in <module>
    line[line.index('-DeviceMap')+1] = '"{}"'.format(int(line[line.index('-DeviceMap')+1]) - 1)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '36\\'
>>>

Comment: Its look like there is some problem with rows where is backslash immediately after the number. But in your example works fine switch the -Acces "system to same row and delete backslash but WORKS :D . Iam confused of it.

Comment: This is the print when i take data from file not directly from code like you: ['  -Name "diSPARE00" -SignalType "DI" -Device "SIM_BOARD" -DeviceMap 1', '', '  -Name "doMotOnState" -SignalType "DO" -Device "DP_BOARD" -DeviceMap 33\\', '  -Access "System"', '', '  -Name "doService" -SignalType "DO" -Device "DP_BOARD" -DeviceMap 44 -Access "All"']

Comment: There is double backslash i think its the problem but i dont know how to solve it. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, problem was that we couldn't convert string that contained non-digit characters like '33\\' using `int()`, so we need to remove that characters before doing that. Updated my answer to handle that case, you can try it.

Comment: Its getting me crazy :D yes now works but all of backslash is missing :D and thats not work in robot one backslash is needed but when i write it like: line[line.index('-DeviceMap')+1] = '"{}"'.format(int(line[line.index('-DeviceMap')+1].replace('\\', '\')) - 1)   its another error. :( Iam robotics guy so sorry for my stupidity in python programing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do it:

1. Split your text with `s.split(' ')` to get an array `arr`
2. iterate over array to find an element equal to "-Phsig"
3. Convert the next element into an integer and substract 1
4. add quotes with `w = '"' + w + '"'`
5. use `" ".join(arr)` to get your text.